# Microchip MPLABX IDE V5.35 conf:default shows blank screen

Tags: microchip, mplab

If I go to properties and try to change MCU type or anything on the fly I can't do this.
I am using windows 10.

[image: See attached image]

Comment: You have to open a project before.

Comment: Or close MPLABx, delete the cache memory and restart MPLABx.

Comment: maybe this helps: https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AO8iBfIyqJJzD8k&id=81424D2B451E88B1%21248&cid=81424D2B451E88B1

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I tried the attached procedure and still, it seems that the problem is not solved. I have other problems but they solved automatically but this one is still creating the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by deleting the "persistence data" following the instruction in the following link. https://microchipdeveloper.com/mplabx:persistence-data

In my case error reoccurs when I activate Proteus VSM addon and restart MPLAB.